# Gitosis on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard, git

I have a Snow Leopard box, where I have gitosis installed (Warning: noob alert), added a git user and I am able to remotely login to the machine with ssh. Locally, I can 'clone' my created repositories, as I can 'clone' the gitosis-admin too. Works perfect.

I clone these using the 'git' user.

```
git clone git@my-remote-machine:reponame.git
```

remotely logged in, what doesn't work:

```
git clone git@localhost:reponame.git
```

However on that same remote machine where the repositories live, I can't clone from the localhost. It asks for a password, which wasn't created as far as I know. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting a password prompt it sounds like you don't have an SSH key set for your user (or if you do it's not one that gitosis recognizes).  gitosis **requires** SSH keys (that it recognizes & has configured for access) in order for it to give you access to the repositories.

It's also possible you created a SSH key with a password, but I hope you'd know if you did that :-)

Comment: so this means i have to create a SSH key for the local user with sshkeygen. And this key in its turn has to be added to keydir of the administration tool?

Comment: Yup - See the gitosis docs & also this excellent blog article on getting gitosis set up for full details: http://vafer.org/blog/20080115011413